# Active Sidebar in React js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

```
import React from "react";
import "./sidebar.css";
import { Link, NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import { MdDashboard } from "react-icons/md";
import {
  FaUserAlt,
  FaListAlt,
} from "react-icons/fa";

const Sidebar = () => {
    return (
      <section className="component-sidebar">
        <div className="component-sidebar-nav">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">
                <div className="component-sidebar-nav-icon">
                  <MdDashboard />
                </div>
                <div>Dashboard</div>
              </Link>
            </li>

            <li>
              <Link to="/my-profile">
                <div className="component-sidebar-nav-icon">
                  <FaUserAlt />
                </div>
                <div>Profile</div>
              </Link>
            </li>

            <li>
              <Link to="/my-courses">
                <div className="component-sidebar-nav-icon">
                  <FaListAlt />
                </div>
                <div>My Courses</div>
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>
    );
}

export default Sidebar;
```

I want to make active side bar, but didn't find any solution. I don't want to use NavLink.I want to make it custom in React js.

If anyone help me. I really appreciate it.  Looking for a solution.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What's an "active side bar"? What's the specific problem you're having?

Comment: Thanks for Responding. I want to apply the active class on sidebar menu. When I click on dashboard. It active the dashboard. But I want to make it custom not using any NavLink or any React Package.

Comment: Have you tried using `useState` to toggle between active navbar states? More info here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: Yes, I tried with this thing but nothing work perfectly.